# intellij, The source preview is slowly when my mouse point is over right's scroll in IntelliJ SDK

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

It's a useful feature for quickly showing preview mini source code.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE6VH.png)

But I don't want to work this function. My Intellij Program was slowly.

Do you know how to cancel it?
I can't find disable this feature Because I don't know what's name of feature.

Do you help me to do disable feature or what's name or Performance tuning?

```html
**My Environment**
MACSierra 10.12.6
Intellij IDEA 15.0 ULTIMATE, Build #IU-143.381
JRE : 1.8.0

**idea.vmoptions**
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=700m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: please raise an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: is there bug tracking service? i will be raising this issue at yourtrack.jetbrains.com/issues